# How to override GIT_OBJECT_DIRECTORY for specific repository?

Tags: git

I'm trying to use a common object directory so that it's easier to handle global blob storage (and, among other things I'm trying to get to, share blobs via IPFS). But I need to make some exceptions.

I set this in my `~/.zshrc`:

```
export GIT_OBJECT_DIRECTORY="$HOME/.local/share/git/objects"
```

It works fine, blobs are centralized, but I don't want to make blobs for *all* repositories public.

Is there a way to override this setting for a specific local repository, so that it uses the normal `./.git/objects` path (or some other)?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170311 might work in some situations.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up doing something similar and finding the autoenv zsh plugin. It's not a git-specific solution though, should I write it up anyway?

Comment: direnv.net ended up being a better solution because there's emacs support for it with github.com/wbolster/emacs-direnv