# How does git know which files not to prune when using a common GIT_OBJECT_DIRECTORY for multiple repositories?

Tags: git

Ever since I started using the `GIT_OBJECT_DIRECTORY` environment variable to centralize blob storage, git operations on individual repositories warn me that there are unreachable objects and that I should use `git prune` to remove them.

But consulting the help for `git prune` gives me the impression that git only considers object references made from the current repository when testing for reachability.

How can I call `git prune` and be sure that git won't accidentally delete objects that are referenced by some other repository on a different directory?

Comment: I don't think you can.

Comment: It seems impossible when one repo does not know the refs of another repo. Why would you want to centralize blob storage?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you can't. For common-object-depot use the `.git/objects/info/alternates` file (usually set up by the clone `-s` or `--reference` option) is more reliable, that way the only objects that make it into the common depot were packed up neatly and published there.

Comment: It looks like you can also use the [`GIT_ALTERNATE_OBJECT_DIRECTORIES`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git/2.10.3) environment variable for this purpose.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart True, but that's not durable and not discoverable, and I don't see any advantages to using it that would outweigh those (or at all, really, not for this use),

Comment: If I set up `.git/objects/info/alternates` or the equivalent env var, how do objects get published to the alternate directory? The manual says "new objects will not be written to these directories," so it seems like this option only works when you know ahead of time the objects you want to reuse, but committing on a repository would still write to its local `.git/objects` directory.

Comment: Incidentally, I'm actually trying to set up a common object store of _unpacked_ blobs, in case that is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55788199/how-to-prevent-git-from-packing-object-files

Comment: It's relevant, and that's not a use I've ever considered.  Of what value is a loose object generated in a single developer's exploratory work to anyone else?  I don't see the point of the exercise.  Anyway, I've never looked in to git namespaces, but from what I know of them I think they might be what you're looking for.

Comment: The point is mirroring the public repository on IPFS. Some exploratory work might get shared too, but in cases where I don't want that to happen I unset the environment variable with `direnv`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55763355/how-to-override-git-object-directory-for-specific-repository. It seems like git namespaces are for sharing objects in the same conceptual repository / project across different clones, but not aggregating objects of separate projects. Git alternates seem like a good solution, but not sure how to "push" new commits to the common object store or how to gc safely.